# I can't upgrade my system, what should I do now?

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

When I update, after some file downloads it shows the below errors.  What should I do now?

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you booting from a LiveCD, LiveUSB, or an installed system?

Comment: booting from usb

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected when booting from USB, and as long as you are connected to the internet, these lines can be safely ignored, as packages can be downloaded from the internet.  Normally you can install a small handful of packages directly from the LiveCD, such as WiFi drivers, but unfortunately this feature does not work with LiveUSBs.

If need be, these packages can be installed using `dpkg` using the .deb files found in the subfolders of the "pool" folder on the USB drive (for example, installing the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package to make certain WiFi chips work).